# SQL statement for getting multiple photos for post

Tags: php, sql

I have a query that gets posts and posts with photos from a user and user's that he follows. This is the query below.

```
$query = "SELECT Posts.*, Profiles.ProfilePhoto, Users.Name, Users.Username, Post_Photos.Photo
          FROM (((Posts
          INNER JOIN Profiles ON Posts.UserID = Profiles.UserID)
          INNER JOIN Users ON Posts.UserID = Users.ID)
          INNER JOIN Post_Photos ON Posts.ID = Post_Photos.PostID)
          WHERE (Posts.UserID = ? OR Posts.UserID in (SELECT Followed FROM Follow WHERE Follower = ?))
          GROUP BY PostID
          ORDER BY Posts.CreateDate DESC";
```

This query will compile and although it gets the results i need there is some bugs.

There first is that with this query  it will only return results where Post_Photos.Photos is true. So the posts that don't have photos are not being returned. I played around with GROUP BY thinking that could work but I could not come to any solution. Is there something I am missing that could still return results from Posts Table without having a value in Post_Photos?

And the second issue is that if there are multiple photos assigned to a postID in my Post_Photos table it creates a post for each photo. To fix that I added a GROUP BY PostID to my query but then only one image will show up.

```
$photo = $row['Photo']; // getting photo from table
```

I played around with a foreach, while loop with $row['Photo'], and tried to make an array but I could not get them to return the photos and then print them to my $output. Any clue on how to fix the issue within my query or if theres a more proper way to get that data would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the first issue, you need to change the `INNER JOIN` on Post_Photos to a `LEFT JOIN`. That will ensure you still get results returned when there are no entries in `Post_Photos` which match the `PostID` i.e.

```
 LEFT JOIN Post_Photos ON Posts.ID = Post_Photos.PostID)
```

If `Post_Photos.Photo` is a string (representing the name of the photo, or a filename), you can resolve your second issue by changing `Post_Photos.Photo` in your select to `GROUP_CONCAT(Post_Photos.Photo)` i.e.

```
SELECT Posts.*, Profiles.ProfilePhoto, Users.Name, Users.Username, GROUP_CONCAT(Post_Photos.Photo) AS Photo
```

Then in your PHP you can do this:

```
$photos = explode(',', $row['Photo']);
```

Comment: ah after doing a little reading on LEFT JOIN I see why that was the fix! Because that I accepted as answer! but with the second one i see an issue with the explode as explode expects 2 parameters.

Comment: Sorry, Ryne, I've just updated the answer with the correct call to explode.